# Make custom image respect tintColor property iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, tintcolor

I have to imagine this has been asked several times, but I must not be wording my question correctly.

I have my own custom image I made in photoshop and it is set as a button's image property. Here it is showing normally:

[image]

The background is transparent, but it is 44x44 with the three dots being a 88x88 pixel .png file. So if I do something like this:

```
self.theButton.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

the image still shows as white. I am not a designer by trade, so I seem to be missing how to properly save or set up the files to make them respect the tintColor property. In photoshop, I usually save these using "Save for web".

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you are looking for are stencil images.

From the UIKit User Interface Catalog:

> Template Images
>
> In iOS 7, you can choose to treat any of the images in your app as a
>   template—or stencil—image. When you elect to treat an image as a
>   template, the system ignores the image’s color information and creates
>   an image stencil based on the alpha values in the image (parts of the
>   image with an alpha value of less than 1.0 get treated as completely
>   transparent). This stencil can then be recolored using tintColor to
>   match the rest of your user interface.
>
> By default, an image (UIImage) is created with
>   UIImageRenderingModeAutomatic. If you have
>   UIImageRenderingModeAutomatic set on your image, it will be treated as
>   template or original based on its context. Certain UIKit
>   elements—including navigation bars, tab bars, toolbars, segmented
>   controls—automatically treat their foreground images as templates,
>   although their background images are treated as original. Other
>   elements—such as image views and web views—treat their images as
>   originals. If you want your image to always be treated as a template
>   regardless of context, set UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate; if you
>   want your image to always be treated as original, set
>   UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal.
>
> To specify the rendering mode of an image, first create a standard
>   image, and then call the imageWithRenderingMode: method on that image.
>
> UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageFile.png"]; myImage =
>   [myImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];

Comment: Both answers are correct, the issue had to do with the way I was accessing my image on my button property.

Answer (score 9):

You might achieve the result you want by using a UIImage with rendering mode [`UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-DontLinkElementID_4).

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Dots"];
UIImage *templateImage = [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
[theButton setImage:templateImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: That's what the docs says to do, I must be futzing something up then as it still is white. I wonder if there are any other common "gotchas" associated with this scenario.

Comment: @JayMorgan as you found a problem on your side maybe remove (or at least edit) your comment to not mislead others :)

Answer (score 9):

### Their are two way to set template image

#### 1.Using Images.assets

[image]

#### 2.Using Code

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageFile.png"];
myImage = [myImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];

imageView.image = myImage;
imageView.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor] // or any other color you want
```