# UIImage change Backgroundcolor

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

All,

We have icon design from PhotoShop, It is Square transparent image with a Polygon inside which has a blue color. Based on some conditions i want to change the Polygon color but on the complete image color. Can we do this in code (Objective C)

[image]

I am attaching a Image in which the Only background "blue" color need to be changed based on the color we give. How can we achevie that

Comment: Yes, In Objective C we have a provision to change the icons colors which are transparently rendered. Here is the procedure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41545599/how-to-change-tintcolor-of-image-in-uibutton-with-imageedgeinsets/41547471#41547471

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/36475407/7250862

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by rendering the image in `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate` mode & after that set `tintColor`.

```
imageView.image = [imageView.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
[imageView setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```